# can lilypond generate this, connect beam on every other note - use voices?

Tags: lilypond, engraving, polyphony

Can lilypond generate this (see attached image), connect the beam on every other note - use voices?  It also has slurs between the 'voices.'

[image: two voices of interleaved (alternating) sixteenth notes]

Comment: LilyPond can definitely generate multiple voices. See, for example, [LilyPond Manual: 1.5.2 — Multiple Voices](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices).

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but…  What does that notation _mean_? How can you slur notes that are simultaneous? (Or if they're _not_ simultaneous, isn't that an abuse of notation?)

Comment: @gidds Not a violinist, but I'd guess that the O notes are played on the open E string and the other notes are played on other strings. Thus those "other string" notes can be slurred/tied on to the notes played on the E string.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, the two voices are clearly to be played on different strings. But I still find the notation highly confusing. Are the two voices to be played simultaneously (using double-stopping), or alternately? If simultaneously, then the slurs/ties are misleading, and I'd suggest best omitted; if alternately, then there are missing rests and/or wrong note values, or the voice-splitting/tail-barring is wrong/misleading.

Comment: It is from the 2nd movement (Allegro) of Violin Sonata in F major, HWV 370 by George Frideric Handel.  As @AndrewLeach pointed out, each 16th note is played separately but on alternating A and E strings.  The slurs indicate bowing (each slurred note pair is played in one bow, either up or down).  So it goes, "c on A string downbow," "e open E string downbow," "e on A string upbow," "e open E string upbow," "b on A string downbow," "e open E string downbow," and so on.

Comment: PS - So the two e notes are not tied but played as separate notes on different strings but in one bow.

Comment: @scanudom That makes musical sense, but to me the notation really doesn't… It's written to _look_ like two independent voices — but it's not, as each means something different on its own! There must be clearer ways of notating this. (E.g. in [the manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bach1sa2.PNG) for his Cello Suite #1 prelude, which has a very similar section, Bach _adds_ extra tails and beams to indicate the second string, but keeps all the notes as straight semiquavers with all the usual tails and beams, so there's no ambiguity.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit complicated to get the slurs to look like they are going between the two voices and the beams to jump over one another, but you only need two voices for this: one with some spacers and the other with hidden notes.

```
\version "2.23.6"

\score {
    <<
        \new Staff {
            \key f \major
            << 
                {
                    \repeat unfold 4 {
                        s16 e''-0[ s e''-0]
                    } | 
                }
                \\
                {
                    c''16[^(\< \once\hideNotes e'') e''-4]( \once\hideNotes e'')
                    b'[^( \once\hideNotes e'') e'']( \once\hideNotes e'')\!
                    c''[^( \once\hideNotes e'')\> e'']( \once\hideNotes e'')
                    b'[^( \once\hideNotes e'') e'']( \once\hideNotes e'')\! |
                }
            >>
        }
    >>
}
```

[image: result of above code]

---

#### Update:

If you look closely at the above image you'll notice that the slurs between the third and fourth notes in each set aren't close enough to the fourth note.  This is because the slur is avoiding bumping into the fourth note's (hidden) downward stem.

Perhaps the easiest way to fix this is to use `\omit Stem` & `\omit Flag` as in your answer (rather than `\hideNotes`).

As suggested in @ksnortum's comment, a macro can be used to simplify the code:

```
oosf = { 
    \once \omit Stem
    \once \omit Flag
}
```

The lower voice can now be written as:

```
...
                {
                    c''16[^(\< \oosf e'') e''-4]( \oosf e'')
                    b'[^( \oosf e'') e'']( \oosf e'')\!
                    c''[^( \oosf e'')\> e'']( \oosf e'')
                    b'[^( \oosf e'') e'']( \oosf e'')\! |
                }
...
```

which will give:

[image: result of code with updates, showing symmetric slurs between the third and fourth note of each set]

Comment: I find that if I'm using `\once\hidenotes` a lot, I shorten it with `ohn = \once \hideNotes`.

Comment: @Elements Very nice clean solution!

Answer (score 4):

Though this may not be the most elegant way, the following worked.

```
\score {
    \relative c''
    \new Staff {
        \key f \major
        <<
            \new Voice {
                \voiceOne
                s16\< e-0[ s e-0]
                s e-0[ s e-0]\!
                s e-0[\> s e-0]
                s e-0[ s\! e-0]
            }
            \new Voice {
                \voiceTwo
                c16[ s e-4] s
                b[ s e] s
                c[ s e] s
                b[ s e] s
            }
            \new Voice {
                \voiceThree
                \override NoteColumn.ignore-collision = ##t
                \omit Stem
                \omit Flag
                \omit Beam
                \slurNeutral
                s16 s e( e)
                s s e( e)
                s s e( e)
                s s e( e)
            }
            \new Voice {
                \voiceFour
                \override NoteColumn.ignore-collision = ##t
                \omit Stem
                \omit Flag
                \omit Beam
                \slurNeutral
                c16( e) s s
                b( e) s s
                c( e) s s
                b( e) s s
            }
        >>
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Aaaand a different idea to expand on:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \denies "Voice"
    \accepts "SuperVoice"
    \defaultchild "SuperVoice"
    }
  \context {
    \name "SuperVoice"
    \type "Engraver_group"
    \accepts "Voice"
    \consists "Slur_engraver"
    \consists "Dynamic_engraver"
    \consists "Dynamic_align_engraver"
    \defaultchild "Voice"
  }
  \context {
    \Voice
    \remove "Slur_engraver"
    \remove "Dynamic_engraver"
    \remove "Dynamic_align_engraver"
  }
}


{
  \key d \minor
  \new SuperVoice
  \voices 2,1
  <<
    \new Voice \with \voiceTwo
    { c''16[(\< s e''-4]( s b'[( s e'']( s c''[( s e'']( s b'[( s e''](\! s }
    \new Voice \with \voiceOne
    { s16 e''-0[) s e''-0]) s e''-0[) s e''-0])\!
      s e''-0[)\> s e''-0]) s e''-0[) s e''-0])  }
  >>
}
```